# Laravel 5.5 Contact Form button does not fire or do anything at all

Tags: php, laravel

this may be some silly thing but I just cant get my button on my contact form to fire or do anything. I have changed the action on the form several times. I don't even get an error, just nothing. I am new to PHP and Laravel.

My Form (on welcome.blade.php):

```
            <form role="form" method="POST" action="/email/send">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
                <br style="clear:both">
                  <h3 style="margin-bottom: 25px; text-align: center;">Contact Form</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control errorBorder" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                  <span id="warningLabel" class="warning wone" style="display:none;">Please enter name!</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                  <span id="warningLabel2" class="warning wtwo" style="display:none;">Please enter email!</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="message" placeholder="Message" maxlength="140" rows="7"></textarea>
                  <span id="warningLabel3" class="warning wthree" style="display:none;">Please enter message!</span>
                  <span class="help-block"><p id="characterLeft" class="help-block ">You have reached the limit</p></span>
                </div>
                  <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit Form</button>
            </form>
```

My Route (web.php):

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::post('/email/send', 'ContactEmailController@send');
```

My email/send.blade.php file:

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body style="background: black; color: white">
    <h1>{{$title}}</h1>
    <p>{{$content}}</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My App\Mail\ContactMailer:

```
    namespace App\Mail;

    use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
    use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
    use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

    class ContactMailer extends Mailable
    {
        use Queueable, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('examplefrom@gmail.com')
                ->view('view.email.send');
}
```

}

My ContactEmailCOntroller.php

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Mail\ContactMailer.php;

    class ContactEmailController extends Controller
    {
      public function send(Request $request)
       {
           $title = $request->input('title');
   $content = $request->input('content');

   Mail::send('emails.send', ['title' => $title, 'content' => $content], function ($message)
   {

       $message->from('examplefrom@gmail.com', 'My Laravel Email!');

       $message->to('exampleto@gmail.com');

   });

   return response()->json(['message' => 'Request completed']);
       }
     }
```

Comment: just change your button type to `submit`

Comment: Wow... such a small thing and it is fixed! Got an error now at least so I can move on... I am new to forms as well. Thanks so much!

Comment: I think you could also use `role="submit"` attribute

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit Form</button>
```